# Porting Arduino code to AVR/C++ input not working?

Tags: avr

So. I'm trying to read an input on the Arduino Nano using C++/AVR/Eclipse instead of the regular arduino IDE.
The code below is working in the arduino IDE

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(5, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  if(digitalRead(5)){
    digitalWrite(13,1);
  }else{
    digitalWrite(13,0);
  }
}
```

I'm porting the code to AVR/C++ in Eclipse, regular blinking leds is working... but I can't read inputs for some reason...

```
#define F_CPU 16000000UL //16MHz
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

#define set_bit(Y,bit_x) (Y|=(1<<bit_x))
#define clear_bit(Y,bit_x) (Y&=~(1<<bit_x))
#define isset_bit(Y,bit_x) (Y&(1<<bit_x))
#define toggle_bit(Y,bit_x) (Y^=(1<<bit_x))

int main( ){
    DDRB = 0xFF;//Setting all portB pins to output (D13/PB5 - LED)
    DDRD = 0x00;//Setting all portD pins to input  (D5 /PD5 - INPUT)

    while(1){
        if(isset_bit(PORTD,PD5)){//if input... doesn't work?
            set_bit(PORTB,PB5);//Set output (Tested to be working)
        }else{
            clear_bit(PORTB,PB5);//Clear output
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the checkmark next to the answer rather than changing the title to indicate that the question has been answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

During the creation of this question I found out the answer... Though I wanted to share it with you guys for later reference.
It has been quite a time since I have worked with AVR.

**You should read pins from PINx**

**You should set pins in PORTx**

**Set DDRx to 1 for OUTPUT and to 0 for INPUT**

^ This is fun because PIC/Microchip MCU's use 1 for input and 0 for output.

See code below:

```
#define F_CPU 16000000UL
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

#define set_bit(Y,bit_x) (Y|=(1<<bit_x))
#define clear_bit(Y,bit_x) (Y&=~(1<<bit_x))
#define isset_bit(Y,bit_x) (Y&(1<<bit_x))
#define toggle_bit(Y,bit_x) (Y^=(1<<bit_x))

int main( ){
    DDRB = 0xFF;
    DDRD = 0x00;

    while(1){
        if((PIND&(1<<PD5))){
            set_bit(PORTB,PB5);
        }else{
            clear_bit(PORTB,PB5);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is interesting, what pins are you reading and writing? And how would you take an analog reading?

Comment: @user2497 The microcontrollers use registers that you can read/write to/from. Arduino is an environment and a wrapper around this, to make it easier and more understandable. You should check the datasheet, to find which registers hold what. The registers are 1 byte (I bits), so you'll have to do some bit manipulation/arethmic and write it to the correct registers.